# how to create thumbnail video uploading time in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, thumbnails

```
use VideoThumbnail;

public function store(Request $request)
    {

VideoThumbnail::createThumbnail(public_path('home_video/1537778425.mp4'), public_path("video_thumbnail/"), 'thumb.jpg', 2, 600, 600);

}
```

Comment: Firstly you should explain you question properly and define all the resources/packages which you have used for it.

Comment: i follow this URL
https://packagist.org/packages/pawlox/video-thumbnail

Comment: after installing packege use    VideoThumbnail::createThumbnail(public_path('home_video/1537778425.mp4'), public_path("video_thumbnail/"), 'thumb.jpg', 2, 600, 600);

Answer (score 0):

1. First Thing You need to give permission to public_path()(Read And Write)
2. Check if the ffmpeg is installed in your system if not

Install it by :

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

and rest of the things are explained in [pawlox/video-thumbnail](https://packagist.org/packages/pawlox/video-thumbnail)

hth